# Is there a way to browse WSDL endpoints using a browser?

Tags: wsdl, endpoint

I want to test the results from a WSDL service in a browser like IE9 or FireFox.  I know that I can view the WSDL XML, but I want to test the return results of an endpoint called `GetEmployeeById` that accepts a parameter called `Id` and returns a class.  I am assuming this is all serialized to XML, so a browser would be a good fit for testing this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Visual Studio for .net development, I think something much better than a browser probably would to use:

```
 wcftestclient <url>
```

which can be called from the command prompt and is part of the tools from visual studio.

The tool will help you to build and receive complex objects and see the results already serialized.

Comment: How to I format the URL to point to the endpoint using the required parameters?

Comment: depends, is exactly the same way you do to generate the proxy, if you are using the traditional web service, you will just point to the url that may end with .svc, and if you are using wcf probably it won't have the extension name. All that is configured in your web.config where you are hosting the service. ***EDIT*** I forgot to mention that you can also call just wcftestclient and then use the UI to point to the url in an address bar.

Comment: The service is hosted by another application.  My application consumes it through a web reference that's added to my VS2010 project.  I can browse the services by navigating to `http://theirsite/services` and then view the WSDL with `http://theirsite/services/employeeservices`.  There, I can see all the endpoints available.  I want to view the results in a browser because I need to debug why a service call is timing out on a remote server, but not my local machine.

Comment: then just use the code I posted like this:              wcftestclient  http://theirsite/services/employeeservices there you will see the endpoints and you can also build your own request with your complex objects

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that VS is not installed on the machine that I publish my app to.  Can this be done from a *web browser*?

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer let's you make a request with simple string parameters if the WSDL provides enough information.

If you haven't seen it, then probably the WSDL is only for discoverability reasons, probably just points to another service in a different transport protocol, not port 80, if the service is not on port 80 you won't be able to use your browser.

You have another more complex tool called FIDDLER that you can format any kind of http request, as well as receiving any kind of requests, like json for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [URL](http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html) to test WSDL endpoints, send request and see response.